# Why do i have to use return twice and how does it work?

Tags: angularjs

I wrote a wrapper for the $http service in angular using a service. Why do i have to return bothe the http call and my result to have it available in a controller?

this is the function in the service:

```
this.fetchData = function(url, parameters)
    {
        if (parameters)
        {
            return $http.get(url, {params: parameters}).then(
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    return response.data.data;
                },
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
        }
        else
        {
            return $http.get(url).then(
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

and this is where i call it in the controller:

```
test.fetchData('/jewelry-room/move-user.action', {user:2000, task:7}).then(
        function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    );
```

Comment: "Why do i have to use return twice" - because these are two different functions you'll be returning from (and at different times, I should add).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because what you return from the factory is a promise: `return $http.get().then()`. Since your factory has the callback function inside `then`, so the promise is resolved. In this case, the function inside controller `then` block will not be called.

You need to return again in order to have access to the response data inside the controller.

Alternatively, just return `$http.get()` from the factory.

Answer (score 0):

You could just return the promise to your controller by using $q:

```
var fetchData = function (url, params) {
    if (params) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get(url, {params: params}).success(deferred.resolve).error(deferred.reject)
        return deferred.promise;
    } else {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get(url).success(deferred.resolve).error(deferred.reject)
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

Then inside your controller you can handle the promise.